# Laravel Migrations with more than one database

Tags: laravel, migration

What are the best practices to manage Laravel Migrations with more than one database?

Answer (score 1):

In your  `app/config/database.php`

Do this

```
return array(

    'default' => 'mysql',

    'connections' => array(

        # Our primary database connection
        'mysecond_database' => array(
            'driver'    => 'mysql',
            'host'      => 'host1',
            'database'  => 'database1',
            'username'  => 'user1',
            'password'  => 'pass1'
            'charset'   => 'utf8',
            'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
            'prefix'    => '',
        ),

        # Our secondary database connection
        'myfirst_database' => array(
            'driver'    => 'mysql',
            'host'      => 'host2',
            'database'  => 'database2',
            'username'  => 'user2',
            'password'  => 'pass2'
            'charset'   => 'utf8',
            'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
            'prefix'    => '',
        ),
    ),
);
```

then in your migrations you can do this

```
Schema::connection('mysecond_database')->create('users', function($table)
{
    $table->increments('id'):
});
```

This will create  the `users` table in `mysql2` connection(database)

to use another connection just change it like this

```
Schema::connection('myfirst_database')->create('posts', function($table)
    {
        $table->increments('id'):
    });
```

if you want to retrieve data from one table

```
$users = DB::connection('mysecond_database')->select(...);
```

if you want to use eloquent you only need to define the connection in the model like so :

```
class users extends Eloquent {

    protected $connection = 'mysecond_database';

}
```

Then you can do it easly like this

```
  $users = User::all();
```

[Source](http://fideloper.com/laravel-multiple-database-connections)